# External display -- Insignia TV cutting off edges?

Tags: display

So I have a 2010 Macbook Air, 1.6GHz, and I am trying to hook it up to an external display, this Insignia:

http://www.bestbuy.com/site/insignia-24-class-24-diag--led-1080p-60hz-hdtv/9844485.p

I have an HDMI -> MiniDisplayPort cable from Amazon that I've connected. In both closed clamshell mode and extension mode, a tiny bit of the screen on all four sides is cut off from the monitor -- the entire top menu bar is cut off, and a bit of the bottom dock is cut off. The settings in Display Preferences is 1080p. I've tried holding alt, and I do not see any listing for 1920x1080 -- I only see 1080i, and lower resolutions, none of which fix the problem of the menu bars being cut off. Could it be the HDMI -> MiniDisplayPort Cable? I've ordered a Male VGA -> MiniDisplayPort and will try that, but in the meantime, does anyone have any other ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing the settings on the TV? Does it have an overscan setting?

Answer (score 2):

In the display settings on your mac for the tv, is there a slider for "Underscan"? That's what allowed me to shrink the picture down a bit so the corners weren't cut off as much.

Answer (score 1):

As @xpereta indicated, you are suffering from overscan.  Unfortunately not all TV's let you disable overscan.  Sometimes they will, but they won't call it overscan - does your TV have a "PC" or "Game" mode?  If so, setting the input you have your Mac plugged into to one of those modes should turn off the Overscan and should thus eliminate the clipping you are seeing.

Comment: setting my TV to Game mode worked for me, I am using Windows 10 and insignia TV 56 inch. thanks much!